# camel-bindy with fixedlength type, can we have body with collection list. I am facing issue

Tags: apache-camel

I have 2 address. 1- XYZ 2- PQR.

Here , I need

```
{
  name: XYZ,
  address:[
          XYZ,
          PQR
   ] 
}
```

I am not able to create list of address when unmarshall.

```
from("file:test").setBody()
.groovy("request.body.subString(35, request.body.length())")
.unmarshall(new CustomeBody()).end;
```